# Running SSIS from remote with WCF

Tags: wcf, ssis

I have a web service calling a ssis with no problem on localhost. But when i deploy it, it doesn't run and doesn't give any error. Where should i change to allow request from remote? I beleive that there is someting prevents requesting... This is my code.

```
public class blaService : IblaService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "runSSISPackage/{Id}")]
    public string runSSISPackage(string Id)
    {
        try
        {
            string pkgLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dtsxPath"].ToString();

            Package pkg;
            Application app;
            DTSExecResult pkgResults;
            Variables vars;

            string databaseName, tableName, minId, maxId, sCreatedDateTime, filePathTemplate, folderName;
            Int64 fileRowAmount, fileCount;
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString.SQL Server (SqlClient)"].ConnectionString.ToString()))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.Table where Id=" + Convert.ToInt32(Id), sqlConnection);
                sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
                SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.Read())
                {

                    databaseName = reader["DatabaseName"].ToString();
                    tableName = reader["TableName"].ToString();
                    minId = reader["MinimumId"].ToString();
                    maxId = reader["MaximumId"].ToString();
                    fileRowAmount = Int64.Parse(reader["FileRowAmount"].ToString());
                    fileCount = Int64.Parse(reader["FileCount"].ToString());
                    sCreatedDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["CreatedDateTime"]).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

                    filePathTemplate = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["outputFilePath"].ToString();
                    folderName = "bla_" + sCreatedDateTime;

                    if (!Directory.Exists(string.Format(filePathTemplate + "\\{0}", folderName)))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(string.Format(filePathTemplate + "\\{0}", folderName));
                    }

                    app = new Application();
                    pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
                    vars = pkg.Variables;
                    vars["DBName"].Value = "bla_PasswordPool";
                    vars["FileCount"].Value = fileCount;
                    vars["FileName"].Value = "bla_" + sCreatedDateTime + "_1of1.txt";
                    vars["FileNamePrefix"].Value = "bla_" + sCreatedDateTime + "_";
                    vars["FileRowAmount"].Value = fileRowAmount;
                    vars["i"].Value = 0;
                    //vars["OutputFolder"].Value = @"C:\SSIS\blaSifreTakip\";
                    vars["OutputFolder"].Value = string.Format(filePathTemplate + "\\{0}", folderName);
                    vars["SelectSQLQuery"].Value = "select sifre from " + tableName + " where  Id>" + minId + "  And Id<=" + maxId + " order by Id";
                    vars["StartRowIndex"].Value = minId;
                    vars["TableName"].Value = tableName;


                    pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null, vars, null, null, null);

                    if (pkgResults == DTSExecResult.Success)
                    {
                        PasswordPackDataInfoEntity pp = new PasswordPackDataInfoEntity(Convert.ToInt32(Id));
                        pp.Status = 2;
                        pp.Save();

                        return "Success";
                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    return "Empty";
                }

            }

            return "";

        }
        catch (DtsException e)
        {

            return e.Message.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a permission issue between IIS and SQL Server (SSIS engine).
In IIS, look at the app pool that your WCF app (IIS folder) is using.  If it is in the default pool, create a new pool and assign a utility account (to make things easier & isolated).  That account needs permission to read files from your (configured) SSIS package folder and it needs admin permissions on the target database.
Here is a discussion thread that explains several pieces to the puzzle.  It is a little wordy, but very thorough: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/ff441dc3-b43b-486b-8be1-00126cf53812/